# How to write fixed width text file with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something that should be easy, but having problems.

All I want to do is generate a report from a MySQL table, and have it as a plain .txt file. I need the file fixed width, so everything lines up and looks good. I'm going to use the courier font, and it's just going to be a barebones table, but how do I actually get everything to line up, the way a fixed-width file should?

Do I have to build up an array of values padded with spaces to get them the same width? or is there a php function to begin writing at a specific position?

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) method. E.g.

```
str_pad('Somevalue', 20, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Will left-pad the string "Somevalue" with spaces, giving

```
"           Somevalue"
```

Whereas

```
str_pad('Somevalue', 20);
```

Will right-pad the string with spaces, giving:

```
 "Somevalue           "
```

Comment: I think that should about do it. Thanks Klaus.

Answer (score 1):

I would still add a [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) before, in case the input value of [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad) is greater than the PAD, the original value is returned, breaking its fixed width.

**Example:**

```php
var_dump(str_pad('Some string with more than 20 input characters', 20));
```

```php
string (46) "Some string with more than 20 input characters"
```

**With substr:**

```php
var_dump(substr(str_pad('Some string with more than 20 input characters', 20), 0, 20));
```

```php
string (20) "Some string with mor"
```

**Working from right to left:**

```php
var_dump(str_pad('Some string with more than 20 input characters', 20, "", STR_PAD_LEFT));
```

```php
string (46) "Some string with more than 20 input characters"
```

```php
var_dump(substr(str_pad('Some string with more than 20 input characters', 20, "", STR_PAD_LEFT), -10));
```

```php
string (10) "characters"
```