# PHP: how can I change variable content of a txt file?

Tags: php, csv

I currently try to find a solution to edit a column of a txt file, the problem is there a no column "endings?". I need to multiple the price by 1.1 & replace it with the new value (fields I need to edit `280,24` and `378,07`)

this txt updates every 12h so the prices change every 12h...

a row looks like this:

```
961983  5031713050124   44661802    3335    OKI 19  Lasertoner  schwarz OKI 44661802    1       ST  280,24  378,07                                  29.05.2020  Lager   Beschaffungsartikel nein
```

anyone has a sugesstion how i could do it?

Comment: May be worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909612/how-to-parse-fixed-width-column-text-in-php which should help in how to read the content, then perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050862/how-to-write-fixed-width-text-file-with-php to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Are the columns of fixed width? Then you could use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) as 

`$data = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $input);`

and search for the term ST in the array and increment the next four fields as 
`$num = (int)$data[index] * 1.1;
$data[index] = $num;`

Then build the string again using [implode()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-implode-function/) as 
 `$input = implode("\number of spaces\",$data);`

Note that this maybe treated as a pseudo code of PHP, the functions exist but since I dont know whether the spaces are fixed or not or the way to write back to CSV I cant write the exact code.

Please forgive me if I couldnt solve the question exactly.